# How to translate my Excel If statement into the SQL Query

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, where-clause

I am having a small issue translating my excel if statement into a CASE clause. Bellow I have posted my current SQL statement and the IF statement i am trying to fit in. Ideally i would like it to sit in the Where clause but if i need another column i will take that. Highlighted in bold is a different header.

Because of the way my where clause is set up it mean i only get half results

IF Statement is `=IF(PD="AC","S",IF(PD="CS","S",IF(PD="CA","S",IF(**PT="SS","S"," ")**)))`

Current SQL

```
SELECT 

AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Order Company`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Sop Order Number`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Order Date`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Order Method`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Payment Method`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Type`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Sub Type`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Description`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Quantity Ordered`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Item Value`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Order Count`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Order Item Narrative`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Group`
, AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Category`

FROM AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.csv AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter

WHERE 
CASE WHEN AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Type` = 'Studio Services' THEN 'Studio Services'
CASE WHEN AEOrdersReceivedCurrentQuarter.`Product Description` IN ('Artwork Charge','Creative Services','Creative Agency','Studio Services') THEN 'Studio Services'
ELSE ' '
End
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking. Are you wanting to limit the records somehow with the `IF` statement?

The `case` will probably look like this:

```
where case 
        when PT='SS' then 'S'
        when PD in ('AC', 'CS', 'CA') then 'S'
        else ' '
      end  = 'S'
```

Comment: I am try to limit the records. What im asking it to do is if column one (PT) says SS then S but if column one is not SS then look at column two (PD) and find 1 2 3 and return it as S also

Comment: I've swapped the `case` order and I believe it will do what you require. You can use this in a `where` clause.

Comment: Hello Sean sorry because i dont have access sql manager im getting kickback from excel on the statement. I will pull the full statement as is un edited above so you can see where its going wrong

Comment: I notice two things wrong. You don't put a `CASE` before each `WHEN` just one at the start - as I have done. It's all one expression from the `CASE` to the `END`. Second thing is `CASE` is an expression, so it returns a value. You will have to check if that value equals something else. I'll update my answer to try and show what I mean.

Comment: So because the CASE statement returns a value does this mean it is probably better of setting this in the select statement and then having the answer display in another column named 'result'? and then in my where clause i can say where result = studio

Comment: Yes, sounds better. You could actually do the `WHERE` clause without a `CASE` anyway. something like `where (PT='SS' OR PD IN ('AC', 'CS', 'CA'))` might be more intuitive.

Comment: I tried where (PT='SS' OR PD IN ('AC', 'CS', 'CA')) but unfortunatly that resricts it to only show the PD 'AC', 'CS', 'CA'  not both